# Call another PHP script and return control to user before the other script completes

Tags: php, email, cron

I'm actually trying to apply this to a script that sends email. The sending email part takes a few seconds which is too long. What I want is for the first script to do its stuff and trigger another script (which sends the Email), but I want the first script to return control to the user without waiting for the second script to send the email.

Options that I have considered:
**Cron Job:** For this I'll have to have a cron job run something like every 2 mins. Not feasible!
**PHP script activating a cron job which deactivates itself when done**: Well ok, but how do I do this? Can PHP do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also call the shell and manually call the PHP file. No cron required and no waiting.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

From the `Notes` Section

> "If a program is started with this
>   function, in order for it to continue
>   running in the background, the output
>   of the program must be redirected to a
>   file or another output stream. Failing
>   to do so will cause PHP to hang until
>   the execution of the program ends."

Comment: Well, just tried it and it waits for the other script before returning.

Comment: "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends." - Mentioned in the Notes section

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! When I first tried it, it went into an infinite loop for no reason at all. And so I used /usr/bin/php-cli thanks to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615713/exec-cause-an-infinite-loop-of-starting-requested-program

Comment: @cwallenpoole you're right, that comment should be part of the answer. I've updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution :

- Your script put a token somewhere (DB/filesystem) when a mail needs to be sent (token may contain data for mail generation)
- A daemon (can be written in php) runs in the background looking for tokens and "eats" them to send mail

I use this kind of solution quite a lot ...

Comment: Oh I tried your solution first, but I'm using a shared hosting and the daemon PEAR lib wanted me to recompile PHP with some options. But if I ever have my own server, this is the way I'm going to use :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery and AJAX to do stuff like this for PHP scripts which take long time.

Comment: Well yes I understand, but in my case the script was supposed to run after a POST to another page and some heavy checking on the server end. So, not a very a safe way in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is something called **beanstalkd**

**Details:** [How can I get a list of all jobs in a beanstalk tube?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772770/158014)

It will allow you to queue up jobs (do 1, then 2, then 3. then 4) you can even distribute these tasks across servers (yes for php jobs!).