# How to run a PHP script asynchronously from a another PHP script?

Tags: php, unix, asynchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call another PHP script and return control to user before the other script completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103528/call-another-php-script-and-return-control-to-user-before-the-other-script-comple)

I need to run a PHP script from another PHP script asynchronously.

---

### Script 1

```
<?php
    echo "Entering main script 1";
    system("php script2.php");
    echo "Exiting main script 1";
?>
```

### Script 2

```
<?php
    echo "Entering script 2";
    sleep(10);
    echo "Exiting script 2";
?>
```

---

In ***script 1***, I use **system()** method to run ***script2.php***. I dont want script 1 to wait for script 2 to complete its execution. How to make it asynchronous? Is there any other method to run a PHP script without using system() function? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103528/ You can use the same solution I provided

Comment: @JohnP: That did't work for me! can you give me an example.

Comment: What was the problem, any error message? Keep in mind you need to send the output of the script to a file (or any other output stream) using the $output and $return_var params. Simply opening up a file descriptor with fopen and passing that should do it.

Answer (score 5):

Add an `&` to the end of the command-line to make the process run in the background on the vast majority of shells. i.e.:

**Script 1**

```
<?php
    echo "Entering main script 1";
    system("php script2.php &");
    echo "Exiting main script 1";
?>
```