# php exec in background not working

Tags: php, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call another PHP script and return control to user before the other script completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103528/call-another-php-script-and-return-control-to-user-before-the-other-script-comple)

Hello,

I'm executing this command in php:

```
exec('php /path/to/script.php one_argument_passed &");
```

But it's not executing it in the background. Is there a setting or something in php I need to do to make this work?

Comment: You might find this useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103528/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a permissions problem.

Comment: This answer is wrong; the only difference between `exec()` and `shell_exec()` is the way the output of the program is returned.